# How to sort one column by two ways

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, sql-insert, sql-server-2016, temp-tables

I have a table called product and its data sample data structer as follows,

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| ProductID | ProductName | SortValue |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1         | AA12        | 0         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 2         | AA10        | 0         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 3         | AA11        | 0         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 4         | AA13        | 0         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 5         | AA1         | 2         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 6         | AA2         | 1         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 7         | AA3         | 4         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 8         | AA4         | 3         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 9         | AA5         | 5         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 10        | AA6         | 6         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

I need to insert this table data into another temporary table with sorting using its `SortValue`. Here you can see multiple `sortvalue` as `0`. Those `0` consists `SortValue` Should be inserted into end of the table by its ProductName. My expected output should be,

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| ProductID | ProductName | SortValue |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 6         | AA2         | 1         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 5         | AA1         | 2         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 8         | AA4         | 3         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 7         | AA3         | 4         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 9         | AA5         | 5         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 10        | AA6         | 6         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 2         | AA10        | 0         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 3         | AA11        | 0         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1         | AA12        | 0         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 4         | AA13        | 0         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

How can I do this? I just tried something like this.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
    [ProductID] INT,
    [ProductName] VARCHAR(50),
    [SortValue] INT )
    
    INSERT INTO @tmp
    p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.SortValue
    SELECT FROm Product p ORDER by p.SortValue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starter: database tables represent *unordered* set of rows. There is no inherent ordering of the rows: when you `select` from a table, you control the order in which rows are returned with the `order by` clause.

So I understand your question as how to *select* rows in the relevant order. For this, you can use a conditional sort:

```
select t.*
from mytbable
order by 
    case when sortValue = 0 then 1 else 0 end,
    sortValue,
    productName
```

The `case` expression in the first level of sorting puts rows where `sortValue` is not `0` first. Then, groups are sorted by `sortValue` and `productName`.